# Give group of rows unique identifier TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Quick question, I have a table with a column that is an identifier for a group of rows. For example a group of rows recording a customers transactions, where each row has the customers reference.

What I am trying to achieve is to give that group of rows a new unique identifier, so I can report on it anonymously.

What I have tried

```
 UPDATE dbo.[t_Health]
   set Code = 'ABC' + Cast(RAND() as varchar(50))
     where si.CustRef= si.CustRef
```

Many thanks!

Comment: ftr - The update statement you've presented can't possible run. The `si` alias is nowhere declared.

Comment: Yes sorry it should of been. where [t_Health].CustRef = [t_Health].CustRef

Comment: While that would work, it is also completely redundant :). You can drop the entire where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new unique identifier, use the `NEWID()` function

```
with    anonymousId as (
        select  distinct CustRef,
                newid() as newId
        from    t_health)
update  dbo.t_health
set     code = ai.newId
from    dbo.t_health h join anonymousId ai on h.custref = ai.custref
```

Comment: I want to unique identify a group of rows with the same identifier. Not give each row a unique number

Answer (score 3):

You can use any one of the [Hashing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2011/08/26/data-hashing.aspx) functions availabe.

**Example**

```
UPDATE dbo.[t_Health]
SET Code = hashbytes('SH2_512', CAST(CustRef AS VARCHAR(16))
```

Comment: @DaveB - Note that theoretically, there's a chance of collisions but practically, most likely the sun will explode before you get one.

Comment: I only 20,000 rows so I think I am safe!